# Getting timestamp from relative date/time string with specific timezone AND specific $now value

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, strtotime

I'm aware of two ways to get a timestamp from a relative date/time string in PHP:

**strtotime**: Allows user to specify their own $now value

**DateTime object**: Allows user to specify their own $timezone value

Is there a way to get a timestamp from a date/time string that allows one to specify both the timezone AND the $now value? It seems like the only way would be to use strtotime while temporarily overriding the default timezone for the entire php application and then setting it back immediately afterwards. That just seems like a hacky solution, and it would be nice if there were a cleaner way.

**Edit:** there seems to be some misunderstanding about what I'm trying to do. Here's a more concrete example:

"I want to find the timestamp corresponding to the string 'next tuesday at 3:00pm' within the America/Los_Angeles timezone AND specifying an arbitrary value for $now, such as March 14th, 2014 at 8:05am."

Comment: See example 2 here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Include the timezone in the date string like [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html): `Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: Mike B is probably the closest so far, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MikeB Thank you for the tip! this was the final trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared an example. This may be want you want:

```
<?php

// Including the timezone int the time strings (thanks @Mike B!!!) 
// will make it very easy.  just strtotime() is required

// create a timestamp for March 14th PDT
$now = strtotime('14 March 2014 8:05am America/Los_Angeles');

// get the requested timestamp.
$nexTuesday = strtotime('next tuesday 3:00 pm America/Los_Angeles', $now);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I was looking for. For example, how would you figure out "next Tuesday at 3 PM in Berlin, assuming the current time is March 14th, 2014 at 9 AM?"

Comment: I see you edited it... it's closer to what I need, but it's still missing the "specifying an arbitrary value for $now, such as March 14th, 2014 at 8:05am" part

Comment: So close! For a second I thought it might actually work, but the problem is that strtotime will use the default timezone, and "next Tuesday 3:00 pm" will mean a different timestamp depending on what your default timezone is, regardless of what the current UTC timestamp is. I want to be able to set that timezone explicitly.

Comment: I would for a second say it doesn't matter. But in case of leap hours (sunlight saving time) it **does** matter. Let me think another little time :)

Comment: How can you say it doesn't matter? "next Tuesday 3:00 pm" in New York vs. "next Tuesday 3:00 pm" in Tokyo is a **14 hour difference**! I'd say it's an incredibly important distinction.

Comment: I noticed you assumed daylight savings time (PDT instead of PST)... will this still work if we don't know if next tuesday is still daylight savings time or not? What if it was "+3 months" instead of "next tuesday"? Regardless, this is probably the closest thing to a solution... I might put "America/Los_Angeles" instead of "PDT" anyway.

Comment: Yeah don't worry too much about it, I think the above might be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: You can use 'America/Los_Angeles'. (I'm selfish astonished again about what is possible with strtotime() and about the requirements of globalization) .. Check my update